# pip install PIL fails

Tags: python, django, pip, python-imaging-library

I am trying to install the pip package PIL. However the install doesn't work throwing the following error.

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pil (from xhtml2pdf==0.0.4->-r virtualenv-reqs.txt (line 16)) (from versions: )
  Some externally hosted files were ignored as access to them may be unreliable (use --allow-external pil to allow).
No matching distribution found for pil (from xhtml2pdf==0.0.4->-r virtualenv-reqs.txt (line 16))
```

The install does work when I have an older version of pip, but with the current version of pip `7.1.2` I am not able to download the package. I am using the following command to install the pip packages

```
pip install --timeout=1000 -i http://pypi.ksjc.sh.colo/simple --trusted-host pypi.ksjc.sh.colo -r virtualenv-reqs.txt
```

What is the issue with this. I thought it might be an SSL issue which is why I added the `--trusted-host` flag. Is there any way to the `--allow-external` flag to be used with the `virtualenv-reqs` file.

Comment: Have you tried installing `Pillow` instead. `PIL` is a bit complicated to install in pip. `Pillow` is a drop-in replacement.

Comment: @RodXavier I am installing `pillow` as well but `pil` is a requirement in another package I am installing called `xhtml2pdf`

Comment: Per the error msg: `--allow-external pil`  (not sure if this conflicts with `virtualenv-reqs`)

Comment: @user3831214 When I look at https://github.com/xhtml2pdf/xhtml2pdf I see in the `requirements.txt` pillow mentioned, not PIL. So PIL is not really a requirement for xhtml2pdf.

Comment: @MichielOvertoom oh that's interesting, then how come it says no matching distribution found for pil (***from xhtml2pdf...***)?

Comment: @Alexander yeah it works using that when I want to just install PIL but is there any way to use that with a `virtualenv-reqs`

Answer (score 94):

Pillow is a maintained fork of PIL, so I recommend using Pillow. But you can't have both installed at the same time.

1. First, remove both PIL and Pillow.
2. Then install Pillow with `pip install pillow` (although, depending on platform, you may need some [prerequisites](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)).
3. Then make sure code is using `from PIL import Image` rather than `import Image`.

Comment: Using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS the only thing that helped me was: `$ sudo apt-get install libtiff5-dev libjpeg8-dev zlib1g-dev libfreetype6-dev liblcms2-dev libwebp-dev tcl8.6-dev tk8.6-dev python-tk`

Comment: I tried this but when I do #3 it says that "No module named PIL"

Comment: @hiquetj I had the same problem.  Solved by adding requirement `pillow >= 4`.

Comment: global name 'PIL' is not defined

Answer (score 15):

You can try using [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/) instead, which is a PIL fork:

```
pip install Pillow
```

To import use following:

```
from PIL import Image
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution that worked for me:

By simply installing the latest version of Pillow using `pip install -U Pillow` I can now call `import PIL.Image`

Answer (score 1):

I'm using PyCharm IDE, and I had this problem. I simply hovered my mouse to the 'PIL' and there's a small pop-up. I clicked more actions and several options appear. I clicked 'Install Pillow, and then, problem solved.

Comment: A link to documentation would make this answer a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0):

One solution was, right-click on 'from PIL import Image' and click
'install Image'

I was on the PyCharm IDE.