# Python - imagescanner on windows failing

Tags: python, windows, pip, image-scanner, pyusb

How to get the Python imagescanner in windows?

[image]

Failing:

Getting access to a scanner device:

```
 from imagescanner import ImageScanner

 # instantiate the imagescanner obj 
 iscanner = ImageScanner()

 # get all available devices
 scanners = iscanner.list_scanners()

 # choose one of the devices
 scanner = scanners[0]

 # scan your file (returns a PIL object)
 scanner.scan()
```

reference: https://code.google.com/archive/p/imagescanner/wikis/GettingStarted.wiki

Comment: I can suggest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32772596/pip-install-pil-fails

Comment: Try an `exe` installer for `PIL`, don't compile it by yourself.